# View on a table referenced by two foreign keys from the same table

Tags: sql

**"Short" version**

I have two tables: `image` and `item`. Items are made of two images: let's call them `left` and `right` (the GUI for an item could be e.g. a canvas with the two images side-by-side). I am trying to setup a report on the images, showing which item "uses" them.

```
+------------+             +------------+
| image      |             | item       |
+------------+             +------------+
| id  <------------+       | id         |
| name       |     |       | name       |
+------------+     +-------- im_left    |
                   +-------- im_right   |
                           +------------+
```

While it is trivial to figure out the query if an item only had a single reference to an image, I have trouble extending this to the "dual reference" case, especially when an item references twice the same image (a perfectly legal scenario given my business constraints).

Until now I was using two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s with aliases to join image to item, using left and right columns. But this construct fails when the same image is used both as left and right (and I can't really explain the result, shown below).

Since this is a pretty common pattern in database design, in such a scenario, how would you design a view that shows each image along with each item it is used by, and from which column it is referenced ?

e.g.

- image_1 is used by item_1 and item_2 (left) and item_3 (right)
- image_2 is used by none (left) and item_4 (right)
- image_3 is used by item_5 and item_6 (left) and item_6 (right)

**Long version** (could be too localized, but shows my trials and specific problem).

Here is the definition of my 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE image (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO image(name) VALUES ('image 1');
INSERT INTO image(name) VALUES ('image 2');
INSERT INTO image(name) VALUES ('image 3');

CREATE TABLE item (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    im_left int,
    FOREIGN KEY (im_left) REFERENCES image(id),
    im_right int,
    FOREIGN KEY (im_right) REFERENCES image(id)
);
INSERT INTO item(name,im_left,im_right) VALUES ('item 1',1,2);
INSERT INTO item(name,im_left,im_right) VALUES ('item 2',1,3);
INSERT INTO item(name,im_left,im_right) VALUES ('item 3',2,3);
```

Until today, I was using this query to build my view:

```
CREATE VIEW imagev_v1 AS (
    SELECT image.id, image.name,
        array_agg(li.id) AS left_ids,
        array_agg(li.name) AS left_names,
        array_agg(ri.id) AS right_ids,
        array_agg(ri.name) AS right_names
    FROM image
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item AS li ON li.im_left=image.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item AS ri ON ri.im_right=image.id
    GROUP BY image.id, image.name
    ORDER BY name ASC
);
```

And it worked quite well:

```
SELECT * FROM imagev_v1;
 id |  name   |  left_ids   |     left_names      |  right_ids  |     right_names
----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------
  1 | image 1 | {1,2}       | {"item 1","item 2"} | {NULL,NULL} | {NULL,NULL}
  2 | image 2 | {3}         | {"item 3"}          | {1}         | {"item 1"}
  3 | image 3 | {NULL,NULL} | {NULL,NULL}         | {2,3}       | {"item 2","item 3"}
(3 rows)
```

Until I added a sneaky item that references the same image in left and right columns:

```
INSERT INTO item(name,im_left,im_right) VALUES ('item 4',3,3);

SELECT * FROM imagev_v1;
 id |  name   | left_ids |          left_names          |  right_ids  |         right_names
----+---------+----------+------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------
  1 | image 1 | {1,2}    | {"item 1","item 2"}          | {NULL,NULL} | {NULL,NULL}
  2 | image 2 | {3}      | {"item 3"}                   | {1}         | {"item 1"}
  3 | image 3 | {4,4,4}  | {"item 4","item 4","item 4"} | {2,3,4}     | {"item 2","item 3","item 4"}
(3 rows)
```

The 3rd result line is strange, to say the least, but I can't explain the behaviour.

I tried another version of the view, which works, but does not have the ability to show the origin of the reference (whether the image is referenced by the `im_left` or `im_right` column):

```
CREATE VIEW imagev_v2 AS (
    SELECT image.id, image.name,
        array_agg(item.id) AS item_ids,
        array_agg(item.name) AS item_names
    FROM image
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item ON item.im_left=image.id OR item.im_right=image.id
    GROUP BY image.id, image.name
    ORDER BY name ASC
);

SELECT * FROM image_v2 ;
 id |  name   | item_ids |          item_names
----+---------+----------+------------------------------
  1 | image 1 | {1,2}    | {"item 1","item 2"}
  2 | image 2 | {1,3}    | {"item 1","item 3"}
  3 | image 3 | {2,3,4}  | {"item 2","item 3","item 4"}
(3 rows)
```

Thank you for reading up to this point, now you get the right to see the actual question: how can I write `imagev_v3` that is correct at all times (unlike `image_v1`), while not suffering from the "loss of origin" problem that `image_v2` has ?

Note that I am using PostgreSQL 8.4, but I think it should be pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join with multiple predicates. It can be an inner join, but if you want to see the images that are not used by any item make it an outer join as written below.

```
Select i.serial imgId, i.text imgName, 
  case when t.im_left is Null and t.im_right Is Null then 'None'
       When t.im_left Is Null Then 'Right'
       When t.im_right Is Null Then 'Left' Else 'Both' End Source,
  t.serial itmId, t.text itmName
From Image i 
   Left Join item t 
     On t.im_left = i.serial Or
        t.im_right = i.serial
```

Comment: Aaahh, so the CASE thing was the trick! Thank you very much for your insight (and time).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that could work for you, similar to what you first tried. You just need to separate joins on your left and right side.

```
SELECT image_id, image_name,
    array_agg(li_id) AS left_ids,
    array_agg(li_name) AS left_names,
    array_agg(ri_id) AS right_ids,
    array_agg(ri_name) AS right_names
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      image.id as image_id, 
      image.name as image_name,
      li.id as li_id,
      li.name as li_name,
      NULL as ri_id,
      NULL as ri_name
    FROM image
    LEFT OUTER JOIN item AS li ON li.im_left=image.id
  UNION ALL
   SELECT 
      image.id as image_id, 
      image.name as image_name,
      NULL as li_id,
      NULL as li_name,
      ri.id as ri_id,
      ri.name as ri_name
    FROM image
    LEFT OUTER JOIN item AS ri ON ri.im_right=image.id

) image

GROUP BY image_id, image_name
ORDER BY image_name ASC
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4e665/9)

Answer (score 0):

(by OP, following rejected edit to @Charles Betana's answer)

Here is Charle's answer, slightly modified to reflect the question.

```
CREATE VIEW imagev_v3 AS (
    SELECT i.id, i.name, 
        array_agg(CASE 
                    WHEN t.im_left<>i.id AND t.im_right<>i.id THEN 'None'
                    WHEN t.im_left=i.id  AND t.im_right<>i.id THEN 'Left'
                    WHEN t.im_left<>i.id AND t.im_right=i.id  THEN 'Right' 
                    ELSE 'Both' 
                END) AS item_sources,
        array_agg(t.id) AS item_ids,
        array_agg(t.name) AS item_names
    FROM image AS i 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item AS t
            ON t.im_left = i.id OR t.im_right = i.id
    GROUP BY i.id, i.name
);
```

Which yields the correct answer:

```
SELECT * FROM imagev_v3 ;
 id |  name   |    item_sources    | item_ids |          item_names
----+---------+--------------------+----------+------------------------------
  1 | image 1 | {Left,Left}        | {1,2}    | {"item 1","item 2"}
  2 | image 2 | {Right,Left}       | {1,3}    | {"item 1","item 3"}
  3 | image 3 | {Right,Right,Both} | {2,3,4}  | {"item 2","item 3","item 4"}
(3 rows)
```